# How do I manipulate html returned in an ajax response?

Tags: jquery

I have searched and tried a number of things for this, but simply cannot get this to work.  I have the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'g.html',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html',
    timeout: 4000,
    cache: false,
    error: function(request, status, error){ alert('Error'); },
    success: function(html){
        alert(html);
        var newData=$('#baa', html);
        $('#result').html('Blah'+newData);
    }
});
```

alert(html) outputs the html contained in g.html.  I am then trying to read in the contents of id='baa' and move that into id='result' in the main document.  My end goal is to manipulate some of that data before it is placed there, but I can't get this simple version working.

g.html looks like this....

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 TRANSITIONAL//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='baa'>
        <ul>
            <li>list 1</li>
            <li>list 2</li>
            <li>list 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I get the full html output if I do **alert(html)**, if I try and do anything with newData I get **[object Object]**.

Completely stumped, any help really appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try...

```
success: function(html){
            var $html = $(html);
            $('#result').html($html.filter('#baa').html());         
         }
```

Comment: note - see my comment to other answer as to why `filter` is used

Comment: That works a treat, thanks.  Is there a way of getting to the <title> and <head> content in a similar way?

Comment: You can get the title text: `$html.filter('title').html()`. I don't know any nice way to get the `head` element though. The `html`, `head` and `body` elements are stripped out with the jQuery constructor `$(html)`, this is why you need `filter` to find `#baa`, as `#baa` becomes a top level element in `$html` (and `find` searches *inside* the top level elements). Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var newData=$(html).find('#baa');
$('#result').html('Blah'+newData.html());
```

Also, worth trying

```
alert(newData.html());
```

...to see more of what's happening (that should prevent the `[object object]` output).

Comment: i don't believe `find` will work here, `filter` is required as `#baa` is a top level element in the parsed jQuery object (see example in my answer)

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet - `#baa` is a child of the `body` element.

Comment: the `body` element does not exist in `$(html)`

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet: Why not? According to the question it exists in the response. Why would jQuery make it disappear?