# Manipulate AJAX response in HTML format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using an AJAX request to return 'raw' HTML content, which I was then planning to manipulate before rendering it on the page. The AJAX request returns the HTML data:

```
function AjaxTest(url){
    $.ajax({
        url: "index.aspx?" + url,
        success: function(result){gatherData(result)},
        dataType: 'html'
    });
}
```

I then call another function called `gatherData(result)` with the result of the AJAX request as the function parameter.

```
function gatherData(data){
  var $data = $(data);

  tables = $data.find('body table');
```

At this point my `tables` var is empty, but I expected it to reference to the tables found within the AJAX responses' body. Is there any way to manipulate the HTML returned via. an AJAX request before rendering it? Below is the HTML response from the AJAX request. All I need to do is access the tables within the body.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
<HEAD>
<title></title>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<TABLE border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 alignment="">
<TBODY>
<TR><TD>x-value</TD><TD>Financial Plan</TD></TR><TD>09/11/2015</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
</TR><TD>10/11/2015</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
</TR><TD>11/11/2015</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
</TR><TD>12/11/2015</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
</TR><TD>13/11/2015</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
</TR><TD>14/11/2015</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
</TR><TD>15/11/2015</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
</TR></TBODY></TABLE><TABLE border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 alignment="">
<TBODY>
<TR><TD>x-value</TD><TD>Business Forecast</TD></TR><TD>09/11/2015</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
</TR><TD>10/11/2015</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
</TR><TD>11/11/2015</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
</TR><TD>12/11/2015</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
</TR><TD>13/11/2015</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
</TR><TD>14/11/2015</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
</TR><TD>15/11/2015</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
</TR></TBODY></TABLE><TABLE border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 alignment="">
<TBODY>
<TR><TD>x-value</TD><TD>Operational Planned</TD></TR><TD>09/11/2015</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
</TR><TD>10/11/2015</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
</TR><TD>11/11/2015</TD>
<TD>66358</TD>
</TR><TD>12/11/2015</TD>
<TD>65990</TD>
</TR><TD>13/11/2015</TD>
<TD>55993</TD>
</TR><TD>14/11/2015</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
</TR><TD>15/11/2015</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
</TR></TBODY></TABLE><TABLE border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 alignment="">
<TBODY>
<TR><TD>x-value</TD><TD>Actual</TD></TR><TD>09/11/2015</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
</TR><TD>10/11/2015</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
</TR><TD>11/11/2015</TD>
<TD>62202</TD>
</TR><TD>12/11/2015</TD>
<TD>59261</TD>
</TR><TD>13/11/2015</TD>
<TD>49119</TD>
</TR><TD>14/11/2015</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
</TR><TD>15/11/2015</TD>
<TD>0</TD>
</TR></TBODY></TABLE>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: What, in what you wrote, it's not working?

Comment: It is not working what so ever, the `tables` var contains nothing.

Comment: This will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17724017/using-jquery-to-build-table-rows-from-ajax-responsejson?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: And data? Can you edit a dump into the Q?

Comment: Please write question properly? where is the problem? to Generate Html from JSON ?

Comment: `data` contains the the response with no problems, the problem occurs when trying to find the `body table` elements. @ParthTrivedi thanks however that is not the solution.

Comment: How about using eval() on your results first?

Comment: As per my view you need to place this data in some div first make that div hidden and then access elements in it

Comment: @ParthTrivedi the question is written plain and simple. "Is there any way to manipulate the HTML returned via. an AJAX request before rendering it?"

Comment: Just curious, why you're returning HTML data instead of a webmethod call? [Webmethod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx(v=vs.90).aspx) will either return json or xml data which will be easy to manipulate and light weight. However, can you update your question with the data that you receive from ajax call? Use Dom inspector to grab data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408571/how-do-i-manipulate-html-returned-in-an-ajax-response may be helpful to you.

Comment: Wrapping HTML string in jq object using `$(HTMLCodeSource)` just returns the `body` content, and so using `$(HTMLCodeSource).find('body')` fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Is there any way to manipulate the HTML returned via. an AJAX request before rendering it?*

In short: Yes!

How?

You are actually doing it correct but partially, You need to have a virtual element to store the response in and that element can be used to manipulate the data before rendering, in javascript `document.createElement()` can be used and `$('<tag>',{option:option})` can be used :

```
function gatherData(data){
  var $data  = $(data),
      tables = $data.find('table'),
      div    = $('<div>', {html:tables});



      div.find('table').each(function(){
         $(this).find('td').append('dynamicValues.')
      });

  $(document.body).append(div);

}
```

Check the snippet below:

```js
var table = '<table><tr><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td></tr></table>';

var div = $('<div>',{ html:table});

$(div).find('td').append(' dynamic values.');

$(document.body).append(div);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

*Can you explain why you need to do so? – **Manticore***

As this question is been asked, i would say that the response is a `string` value which have some `html` tags, so directly htmlstrings are very hard to manipulate, so best way is to create a dummy element in the memory as suggested above and place the htmlstring in it, now javascript can be used to manipulate it because that has been now placed as a valid html.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to do so?

Comment: will add in the answer @Manticore

Answer (score 0):

You have to do like

```
var table = $("body").append("<div id='dataDiv'>"+data+"</div>").find("table");

$("#dataDiv").remove();
```